# pandas groupby; counting overlapping colums

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

ID     A   B   C   D 
6234   1   0   1   0
3417   1   0   0   0
9954   0   1   0   0 
4369   0   0   0   1
6281   1   0   1   0

And I want to group it so as to make it look like this:
                ID
A   B   C   D
1   0   0   0   3
1   0   1   0   2
0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   0   2
0   0   0   1   1

I have been using the following code, which has not gotten me very far.
    import pandas as pd

```
data = [[6234,1,0,1,0],
        [3417,1,0,0,0],
        [9954,0,1,0,0],
        [4369,0,0,0,1],
        [6281,1,0,1,0]]

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','A','B','C','D'])
DF2 = DF1.groupby(['A','B','C','D']).count()
```

I would appreciate any insight that anyone might have to offer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by overlapping columns in more detail?  I don't quite understand the result DataFrame you want to achieve.

Comment: Currently, if I perform a groupby(['A','B','C','D']).count(), I only get the count for the values in each column A, B, C, D. I am completely ignoring those records where I could have (for example) A = 1 AND C = 1, or B = 1 AND C = 1. This is what I mean by overlapping; there is a 1 in more than one column within the same record. I would like to have a separate count for those records as well.